# Automapper copy based on destination value

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I am trying to copy source value only if the destination value is null. I am using the following map

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<BM.AudioSetting, BM.AudioSetting>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.MSOffsetInherited, opt =>
                                                       {
                                                           opt.Condition(src => src.DestinationValue == null);
                                                           opt.MapFrom(src => src.MSOffset);
                                                       });
```

In my condition I am checking to make sure the destination value is null before mapping. The problem is the copying is happening all the time regardless of the destination value.

Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks
Isam

Comment: It looks correct.  What version of Automapper are you using?  Can you show the class definition of BM.AudioSetting along with the data that exists that isn't mapping correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. Probably you're expecting src.DestinationValue to be the destination object's property. If so, custom [type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) should help you to achieve desired behavior.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441061/192723) should help you with creating custom type converter.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your source and destination types are the same. Are you essentially trying to clone the object when the destination value is null? If so, then AutoMapper may not be the appropriate solution as per the comments on this question: [Copy object to object (with Automapper ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713556/copy-object-to-object-with-automapper)